# Tokens and Grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, token, grammar

Reading through Programming:Principles and Practice Using C++ . On Chapter 6 were creating a calculator and using tokens to identify each character of the equation one by one. Then we use a Grammar to set the rules for each element (I believe?). Now both of these I dont understand properly. He jumps through some of this text without properly explaining and assumes that you just "get" whats going on. Or Im missing something.

**Tokens:**

So I understand that we "split" or tokenize? each element so they can be evaluated separately. But I dont understand how they are created?

Here is their example:

```
class Token {       
    public:
        char kind; 
        double value; 
};
```

So from what I understand is. We create a class called Token. We make it public. Then inside this class we define 2 variables kind and value. Next do we initialise the variables below?

```
Token t;                // t is a Token 
t.kind = '+';          // t represents a + 
Token t2;                  // t2 is another Token 
t2.kind = '8';             // we use the digit 8 as the “kind” for numbers 
t2.value = 3.14;
```

So my question for tokens is. Why are the values '+', '8' and 3.14? Could they be anything or is there a reason its 8? and why value 3.14? Can t.kind be '-', or '*' etc?

**Grammar:**

So ive now learned that a grammar can be defined by any terminology I want, but reading the following grammar doesn't make sense to me.

```
// a simple expression grammar: 
Expression: 
    Term 
    Expression "+" Term         // addition 
    Expression "–" Term         // subtraction 
Term: 
    Primary 
    Term "*" Primary             // multiplication 
    Term "/" Primary              // division 
    Term "%" Primary               // remainder (modulo) 
Primary: 
    Number 
    "(" Expression ")"             // grouping 
Number: 
    floating-point-literal
```

Could someone possibly come up with a smaller example. I dont understand how he got the above grammar from 45+11.5/7 . I understand that we need to set a rule for this program so that it will evaluate *, / and () before + and -. But how does the above tree accomplish that?

Comment: Did you read all of section 6.4? The author provides a long explanation of what this grammar means and how to use it to analyze an expression. (Also, he says that using '8' was an arbitrary choice, and that kind is usually the operator character. Later in the book, you will find a cleaner solution.)

Comment: @rici Yes I did read all of 6.4 maybe I’ll go over it again and see if something sticks. And regarding the number 8, what’s the point of it, if it doesn’t store the actual value? You explanation poses similar questions as I’ve asked above...what’s the 3.14 then...if you understand it why not provide an example in a different light. 2nd he also never shows us how to define our own Grammar. Just an example of already made ones. No steps showing how you decide what 'rules' to define either.

Comment: The only point of the '8' is to identify the "kind" of the token (a floating point number). Mist of us these days would use `enum`s but I don't think you've gotten to them yet. It could have been any character, other than the ones used for other kinds of tokens, such as operator tokens. So the `8` tells you "this is a number"; you have to look at the value field if you need the value if the number. But for parsing, you don't need the value; you only need the value when you want to compute the expression, which you only do after you've parsed it.

Comment: As for the grammar, creating grammars is a very big topic and well beyond the scope of an beginning programming text. That's why he just gives you the grammar. But he does spend several pages explaining it and I honestly don't think I or anyone else could do better in a couple of hundred words. It's not a TL;DR topic.

Comment: @rici thanks for the replies rici. So where he goes Token t; t.kind = '+'. Is this just an example or are we required to initialise it like this?

Comment: If the token in the input is a `+`, then its representation in your program has the `kind` field set to `+`. (It's his convention, not a rule. You could use any convention you wanted to, as long as you use it consistently. But his is easy to remember :-)

Comment: But he manually set token t to '+'. Whats the reasoning for this?

Comment: It's just an example. More realistic code which creates tokens by reading input appears later in the chapter. He's just trying to show you how the tokens `+` and `3.14` are represented as Token objects.

Comment: ok I thought as much. I wish he wouldnt jump back and fourth so much and be clearer, it gets really confusing as to what is used code or just example...